# cross-compiling GTK for Raspberry Pi

Tags: c, linux, cross-platform, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I am trying to complete this tutorial <s>[here]</s>[here](https://web.archive.org/web/20160322062248/http://hertaville.com/2013/07/19/cross-compiling-gtk-applications-for-the-raspberry-pi/). I am running Ubuntu 32bit and I am trying to cross compile for a Raspberry Pi with Raspbian.

When I ran make, I get his error:

```
/home/alby/rpi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/../lib/gcc /arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8.3/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: warning: libgraphite2.so.2.0.0, needed by /home/alby/rpi/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libharfbuzz.so.0, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/home/alby/rpi/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libharfbuzz.so.0: undefined reference to `gr_seg_advance_X'
/home/alby/rpi/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libharfbuzz.so.0: undefined reference to `gr_slot_can_insert_before'
etc..
```

libharfbuzz.so.0 is in the correct location. I checked for dependency

```
readelf -d libharfbuzz.so.0 | grep NEEDED
```

and this is the output:

```
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libgobject-2.0.so.0]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libglib-2.0.so.0]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libfreetype.so.6]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libgraphite2.so.2.0.0]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libgcc_s.so.1]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libc.so.6]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [ld-linux-armhf.so.3]
```

This is the first time I try cross-compilation, maybe I am missing something very obvious, but I cannot find out what it is.
thanks Alb

Comment: What's not found is libgraphite2. Is that in place (in the target tree)? ld cannot find it.

Comment: I have never used or compiled for a Raspberry but I read that it has an ARM processor. That means that you cannot use your system libraries (note the "i386") for the cross compiling. The cross compiling environment must provide (i.e. build or install) the ARM versions of all needed libraries and set up the paths for the linker. Yours seem to be in /home/alby/rpi/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/.

Comment: no it is only present in my local machine. So, do I need to install something in the Raspberry file system and overwrite the target tree in my local machine ?

Comment: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/ this is a copy of the PI file system.

Comment: Just from superficially reading the error message I would assume you need libgraphite2, yes; and if you are copying or mounting the pi file system you should probably install it on the pi. You'll need it there later nayway for running GTK progs since it's a dynamic lib.

Comment: Peter, found what was wrong. The library libgraphite was installed in the remote file system, but the Makefile of the tutorial was not pointing there. I just needed to add a line: XLINK_LIBDIR += $(HOME)/rpi/usr/lib. Thanks!!